# Tips on getting Hudson / Jenkins working on Unix System Services z/OS

Tags: hudson, zos

I've read that it is possible to get a Hudson slave running on [zOS (under Unix System Services).] (http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/Hudson-slave-to-z-OS-td2265091.html)

When I try it (even with the JVM option -Dfile.encoding=ISO8859_1) I get:

```
[11/30/11 22:09:40] [SSH] Checking java version of /userhome/mjb/hudson/jdk/bin/java
[11/30/11 22:09:44] [SSH] /userhome/mjb/hudson/jdk/bin/java -version returned 1.6.0.
[11/30/11 22:09:44] [SSH] Starting sftp client.
[11/30/11 22:09:46] [SSH] Copying latest slave.jar...
[11/30/11 22:09:57] [SSH] Copied 216,629 bytes.
[11/30/11 22:09:58] [SSH] Starting slave process: cd '/userhome/mjb/hudson'  && /userhome/mjb/hudson/jdk/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=ISO8859_1 -jar slave.jar
<===[HUDSON REMOTING CAPACITY]===>   java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: D0D20009
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.<init>(Channel.java:364)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.<init>(Channel.java:276)
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.setChannel(SlaveComputer.java:297)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.startSlave(SSHLauncher.java:322)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.launch(SSHLauncher.java:184)
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer$1.call(SlaveComputer.java:184)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[11/30/11 22:10:01] [SSH] Connection closed.
```

I am currently using Hudson ver. 1.376.  Is it worth upgrading?  Any other tips greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 3):

The magic option is -text. 
Launch your slave with:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=ISO8859_1 -jar slave.jar -text
```

It will fix the communication issue.

Answer (score 0):

The page you mention says that it *should* be possible.  But the defect that was open at https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-13091 is not resolved yet... :(