# Jenkins slave supported platforms?

Tags: jenkins, mainframe, zos, slave

Can Jenkins slave be installed on Mainframe? Over the years, I've built a DevOps solution with IBM ClearCase (has a z/OS extension) , ClearQuest and BuildForge (has an agent on z/OS) which supports Mainframe, Informatica, Unix and Windows. Now I am thinking about migrating it to the modern tool such as Jenkins to replace BF, JIRA to replace CQ and Git to replace CC. I am not sure if I can do that with the z/OS piece, need a way to submit job to mainframe and get back the result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tips on getting Hudson / Jenkins working on Unix System Services z/OS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333863/tips-on-getting-hudson-jenkins-working-on-unix-system-services-z-os)

Comment: Talk to the Mainframe support people. See if you can submit jobs with FTP and retrieve output from those jobs in the same way. Would that do you? Depends on what is set up for FTP use. If not like that, they may have a preferred way for remote job-submission and retrieval.

Comment: I just found there is a Jenkins plugin called "IBM z/OS Connector - This plugin provides connectors between Jenkins and IBM zOS including integration of IBM SCLM as SCM." It provides a Submit Job build step.